# Second degree parametric inequalities

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, parametric

I am asked to solve the parametric inequality and to find for which values of **a** every **x** is a solution.

$$
 (a+5)x^2 - 2x(a+1) + 2a - 4 \ge 0
$$

So in order every **x** to be a solution to the inequality we need the discriminant $ \le 0$.

So I get $ -4a^2 - 16a + 84 \le 0 $

When I solve it I get that $x \le -7 \cup x \ge 3 $

The problem comes from the fact that in the solutions of the exercise it shows only $ x \ge 3 $

Why is that ? Am I missing something ? I think for all 10 exercises its showing only 1 root.

Comment: You also want the first coefficient $a+5\geq 0$, otherwise the result is opposite, i.e., there will be no solution for the inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: The discriminant being negative only tells you whether the graph lies completely above or completely below the x axis. You need more conditions to check for it being completely above..